# View coordinates are messed up

Tags: objective-c, view

Im having this mistake, anyone know how to fix it.
All the coordinates are wrong.

Here is a picture when i set manually te x and y to 0
[Error 1 http://bonsai.com.ec/elio/Captura%201.png](http://bonsai.com.ec/elio/Captura%201.png)

When I move the label to position 0 its show like it's on 160 on x
[error 2 http://bonsai.com.ec/elio/Captura%202.png](http://bonsai.com.ec/elio/Captura%202.png)

The problem is that when I run it some objects take the original coordinates, some don't. I've tried using auto layout, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the word "Origin" in your screenshots. You've selected a center origin for this view. To fix this, select the dot in the upper left corner of the box above "Origin."

Comment: beat me by 2 seconds.